# compile error in AppDelegate.swfit when upgraded to Xcode 6.1

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

After upgrading to **xCode6.1**, I can't compile my project which is ok last time. I have never changed anything in this file. Please help me !!!

AppDelegate.swift:75:29:

`errorWithDomain(_:code:userInfo:)' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSError(domain:code:userInfo:)`

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

// The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.

// Create the coordinator and store

var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("PassNote.sqlite")

var error: NSError? = nil

var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {

coordinator = nil

// Report any error we got.

let dict = NSMutableDictionary()

dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"

dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error

error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

// Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.

// abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")

abort()

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using this command in Xcode:
cmd + shift + k

Ah, i see. I am also developing in Swift and they changed some of the standart implementations.

All you need to do is change the function into what Xcode is saying.. :) I had like 90 changes in my project.

So you need to change it to this:
`NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)`

Comment: Nice one, what a faff!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when running my code in the new Xcode 6.3 Beta. This is part of the CoreData code that is generated, when you first create your app.

*********************************Before*******************************************

// Report any error we got.

let dict = NSMutableDictionary()

dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"

dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error

error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

// Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.

// abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

NSLog("Unresolved error (error), (error!.userInfo)")

abort()

********************************After*********************************************

`var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

if this error is showing you in **core data** just delete/uninstall your app from simulator or  phone(if you are running in phone) Click **shift + cmd + H** for go to Home and long press on app icon and now clean and built your app.

Clean - shift + cmd + k

Built - cmd + B

Run it.

This error shows because of you copied your project's folder from one computer and transfer it to another.

Answer (score -1):

Reset content and settings on iOS Simulator worked for me.

Comment: this is a comment.  you'll have to wait until you have enough reputation and then you can post them.